# How to round to the nearest penny?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

Column GrossCommission displays value 368.760000 but I need it to be 368.75.

Column NetDueCarrier displays value 31.240000 but I need it to be 31.25

Below is the calculation for those values:

```
SELECT  
        policyNumber, 
        CompanyCommission, 
        CASE WHEN [GrossPremium] < 0 THEN [BondAmount] * (-1) ELSE [BondAmount] END  as [NetPenalLiability],
        GrossPremium as WrittenPremium, 
        PayableFees, 
        (GrossPremium * (CompanyCommissionActual /100)) as GrossCommission, 
        BillDate, 
        PolicyType,
        ((GrossPremium -  (GrossPremium * (CompanyCommissionActual / 100))) + PayableFees) as NetDueCarrier
```

[image]

Comment: Did you actually mean "round to the nearest quarter"?

Comment: Do you need to round to the nearest penny, round to the nearest 1/12th of a dollar, or round to the nearest quarter? Your question and examples conflict.

Comment: In what logical way can rounding from 368.760000 to 368.75 be called "rounding UP to the nearest penny"?

Comment: @TabAlleman: I would just assume it's the latest IEEE standard. :P

Comment: Schema, please. Without data types it is difficult to pin down truncation and rounding issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the value to the nearest 5 cent, then you could use something like this:

```
create table t (val decimal(9,4));
insert into t values
 (31.20),(31.21),(31.22),(31.23),(31.24)
,(31.25),(31.26),(31.27),(31.28),(31.29);

select 
    val
  , Nearest5 = round(val/.05,0)*.05
  -- , Nearest5 = round(val*20,0)/20 -- alternate way of writing the expression
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UUNA22566

returns:

```
+---------+----------+
|   val | Nearest5 |
+-------+----------+
| 31.20 | 31.20    |
| 31.21 | 31.20    |
| 31.22 | 31.20    |
| 31.23 | 31.25    |
| 31.24 | 31.25    |
| 31.25 | 31.25    |
| 31.26 | 31.25    |
| 31.27 | 31.25    |
| 31.28 | 31.30    |
| 31.29 | 31.30    |
+-------+----------+
```

Comment: This is good. OP, substitute .05 to .25 if you're trying to round to the nearest quarter.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any function created for this rounding?

Comment: @Oleg I think inline code for this is simple enough to avoid a function, but if you do want it as a function then be sure to use an in-line table valued function. Scalar functions can slow things down. Read this for more info: [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply wrap the calculation in a `ROUND` function:

```
ROUND(GrossPremium * (CompanyCommissionActual /100), 2) as GrossCommission,
...
ROUND((GrossPremium -  (GrossPremium * (CompanyCommissionActual / 100))) + PayableFees, 2) as NetDueCarrier
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql). This is assuming you're using SQL Server with a version >= 2008.